# Confirmation of Interest and financial mathematics problem

Tags: finance

I'm having trouble with two questions

1. A fund earns a nominal rate of interest of 6% compounded every two years.  Calculate the amount that must be contributed now to have 1000 at the end of six years.

My thoughts:

Since it is compounded every two years, then the interest is divided by $.5$, so I get:

$Present Value = 1000*1/(1+2*0.06)^3$ = $711.78$

Is that correct?

Comment: Is this an actuarial science (exam FM) question?

Comment: @Clarinetist No, a textbook question I'm trying to figure out

Comment: Could you give more context? What textbook is this? Is this in a finance class, math class, or actuarial science class?

Comment: Mathematical Finance class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

This answer assumes that you know actuarial notation. Judging by your previous questions, you do. We have $$i^{(1/2)} = 0.06$$
(why?), and thus the effective rate is 
$$\dfrac{i^{(1/2)}}{1/2} = 0.12\text{.}$$
This is the two-year effective rate. Six years is equivalent to three two-year periods. The equivalent discount factor is $$v = \dfrac{1}{1.12}$$
so the present value of $1000$ from three two-year periods is 
$$1000v^{3} = \dfrac{1000}{(1.12)^3}$$
which matches your answer.